# Why can I connect to a device in my network with an external address but not an internal IP?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

We have a Y-cam Black CCTV camera that is connected to our network. It was initially connected by a LAN cable for the setup, and once that was done we left it to use the wireless connection. When using a cable, we can access the web interface fine, but when connected to wireless we can't get to it. The web address we use is `http://192.168.6.100:8000`. This IP configuration is set up on the router side - the camera uses DHCP (though it does specify it's own port).

At first I thought the wireless wasn't working, but when we tested the alarm/movement sensor, email and FTP upload functionality while connected to wireless it worked perfectly. We have DDNS set up on our router, and accessing `http://oururl.dyndns.org:8000/` in a web browser shows the control panel fine. Also, using the iPhone app or simply using telnet to access it works just fine. However, explicitly using the IP address it doesn't work.

```
C:\Users\leonardc>telnet 192.168.6.100 8000
Connecting To 192.168.6.100...Could not open connection to the host, on port 8000: Connect failed
```

I'm unsure why this would happen - I can't see it being a firewall problem (all outbound from my PC is allowed - the default Windows setup). I'm fairly sure it's the router though - we have just put it in. Before we had a Netgear DG834G - we have replaced it for a Netgear DGND3700v2.

**Edit:**

Here is a screenshot of the attached devices screen on my router, showing it is using 192.168.6.100

[image: Attached Devices]

Here is a screen shot of the CCTV status page, showing it using 192.168.6.100

[image: Network Configuration]

UPnP is turned off on the router completely.

This is the inbound rule in the firewall config on the router:

[image: Inbound firewall rule]

Wireless isolation is turned off - so it can't be this either.

**Further Edit:**

I have changed the IP and Port to two completely new ones - restarted the router and the camera. Exactly the same problem aterwards: I can connect with the DynDNS address but not the local IP/Port combination. Running out of ideas here... Y-cam support are useless.

Unfortunately there is no logging on the camera and the logging on this router is pretty basic - there doesn't seem to be an option to increase it to a higher level unfortunately.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have tried to ping it? Do you have that problem from other computers, too, or just this one? What have you configured on your router to forward the networktraffic to the cam?

Comment: Yes I've tried to ping it. This happens from any computer on the LAN. On the router I have a custom service (port 8000) and a firewall rule that uses it to make sure data is allowed through to 192.168.6.100 on port 8000. As I said, that works fine - even when accessing it internally (still using the dyndns url)

Comment: And did it respond to your ping?
Can you upload a screenshot of that forwarding rule on your router?

Comment: No, it didn't respond to ping (though I'm not sure if the CCTV is even supposed to respond to ping). Added screenshots, but I don't see how it's relevant as it's just an inbound rule - I am accessing it by IP on the specific port, and using the external address it works anyway.

Comment: My last thought is, that your router puts lan and wlan devices in different networks or at least prohibits wlan devices to communicate with other devices (I know that Fritz!Boxes have or had such a feature). Look out for something like that.

Comment: Check the logs on your router. You may need to temporarily switch logging to maximum detail. Also check to see if your camera has any logging capabilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug in the firmware. Netgear have had a beta firmware (v12_t4) for months that fixes this issue, but strangely refuse to take it out of beta and publish it on their website.

I found a copy of the firmware by following the posted link on this forum...

http://forum1.netgear.com/showthread.php?t=77750&page=4

Clearly it's an issue with ARP resolution, and the beta firmware fixes that.

HTH.

Toby

Comment: In the office tomorrow - I will check it out and upvote/mark as answer accordingly - thank you!

Comment: To prove it's the router, enable wireless isolation, save, and then disable it. Watch the problem go away temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answers, this issue was caused by a well-known bug in the router firmware.

As of 2015, I have found this is now fixed in version 1.1.00.23 of the firmware (for all regions except North America & Germany).

Comment: On a forum, posts can be anything (answers, comments, etc.).  Super User's purpose is to build a knowledgebase and it relies on the structure of questions being questions and answers being solutions to the questions.  Your answer could have been mistaken for simply confirmation of another answer, which might have been deleted as a non-answer. I edited it to remove some of the extraneous commentary so the new information it contains stands out.

Answer (score 0):

In short, the IP changed. The wireless device shows to the router as a different interface than the wired networking, so the router created a new DHCP lease for it with a different IP address. If you can view the list of DHCP leases that the router has given out, you should be able to find what the new IP is fairly easily.

It's likely magically working due to the camera using UPnP to automatically forward the ports on the router to it's own IP.

Comment: Check my edit. The IP hasn't changed - it's 192.168.6.100. UPnP is switched off completely on the router.

Comment: Also changed the IP and port and the same problem persists - see my latest updates

Answer (score 0):

Check if:

- you're using a proxy that's not properly configured for local network
- your desktop-firewall is blocking the traffic (disable it for testing purposes)
- your router prohibits WLAN devices to communicate with other LAN devices
- your actual used client devices is the only one that has problems reaching the cameras web interface
- the ip address of your camera is still the right one

Comment: * No proxy
* It's not - also disabled and no difference
* Doubtful - can share files from a laptop connected via wifi
* No, it's all
* Yes, it's still the right one

Comment: Is it possible to define accesslists in the camera? Maybe it's the camera blocking you.

Comment: No - and the camera hasn't changed - only the router has - but wireless isolation is switched off and everything is set up the same. Odd one!

Answer (score 0):

There is a fault with the dgnd3700v2 that isolates the wifi.

Comment: Can you link me to anything that confirms this?

Comment: Or add more details to how this actually solves the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try a full reset of the router and make sure you have the current firmware .12 on the dgnd.

Hold reset until all lights blink. Keep holding rest and unplug wore cable wait 10 secs or so and plug power cable back while holding reset button down for about 20 secs.

Reconfigure router with the settings required by ISP and your devices.....

Hope that works...

Cheers
Anthony